# Retrieve data in sets Pandas

Tags: json, pandas, api

I'm retrieving data from the Open Weather Map API. I have the following code where I'm extracting the current weather from more than 500 cities and I want the log that is giving me separate the data in sets of 50 each

I did a non efficient way that I would really like to improve!

Many many thanks!

`x = 1`

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():

base_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"

units = "imperial"
query_url = f"{base_url}appid={api_key}&units={units}&q="
city = row['Name'] #this comes from a df

response = requests.get(query_url + city).json()


try:        
df.loc[index,"Max Temp"] = response["main"]["temp_max"]

if index < 50: 
print(f"Processing Record {index} of Set {x} | {city}")

elif index <100: 

x = 2

print(f"Processing Record {index} of Set {x} | {city}")

elif index <150: 

x = 3

print(f"Processing Record {index} of Set {x} | {city}")

except (KeyError, IndexError):
    pass
    print("City not found. Skipping...")
```

Comment: I believe this question is better suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: improved syntax